# Magnolia CMS and Blossom module exception

Tags: java, magnolia

I'm trying out magnolia (v 4.4.6) with blossom (v.1.2.3) for spring integration. After installing and restarting tomcat, I see an error: (Any idea how to fix this?)

```
2012-01-27 11:05:56,733 INFO  info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.MIMEMapping        : 

Registering event listener for MIMEMapping
2012-01-27 11:05:56,735 INFO  info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ConfigLoader       : Configuration loaded (took 7 seconds)
2012-01-27 11:05:56,926 WARN  gnolia.content2bean.impl.Content2BeanProcessorImpl: can't resolve class for node /server/filters/cms/blossom
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NestedIOException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at info.magnolia.objectfactory.DefaultClassFactory.forName(DefaultClassFactory.java:52)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.impl.Content2BeanTransformerImpl.resolveType(Content2BeanTransformerImpl.java:110)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.impl.Content2BeanProcessorImpl.toBean(Content2BeanProcessorImpl.java:77)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.impl.Content2BeanProcessorImpl.toMap(Content2BeanProcessorImpl.java:178)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.impl.Content2BeanProcessorImpl.toBean(Content2BeanProcessorImpl.java:94)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.impl.Content2BeanProcessorImpl.toMap(Content2BeanProcessorImpl.java:178)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.impl.Content2BeanProcessorImpl.toBean(Content2BeanProcessorImpl.java:94)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.impl.Content2BeanProcessorImpl.toBean(Content2BeanProcessorImpl.java:68)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.Content2BeanUtil.toBean(Content2BeanUtil.java:149)
        at info.magnolia.content2bean.Content2BeanUtil.toBean(Content2BeanUtil.java:135)
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.createRootFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:151)
...
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solved it by adding the following dependencies to my custom module:

```
org.springframework:spring-webmvc
org.springframework:spring-core
org.springframework:spring-web
```

I am not sure if all those dependencies are required. Looking at the blossom pom.xml (http://svn.magnolia-cms.com/view/community/modules/blossom/magnolia-module-blossom/trunk/pom.xml), spring-webmvc has `scope="provided"`, which indicates that spring-mvc is meant to be available in one form or the other. But at least it works with those explicit dependencies